# Fast splitting of a vector and component wise mean

Tags: r, mean, large-data

How can I write a fast function, that will

- partitionate a dataframe in 4 parts of the same length w,x,y,z
- return the per-index mean of w,x,y,z 
  this mean should be `m=(w+x+y+z)/4`   (note that these are letters all vectors)

Example data may look like this:

```
# my data + noise 4 times
a <- 1:1000 + rnorm(10)
b <- 1:1000 + rnorm(10)
c <- 1:1000 + rnorm(10)
d <- 1:1000 + rnorm(10)

mydf <- data.frame(time=1:4000, measurement=c(a,b,c,d))
```

Till now I use the following slow workaround. And apply the function on `mydf$measurement`

```
AvgOverPeriodsVector <- function(hdata, recordedperiods=4){
  SamplesPerPeriod <- length(hdata)/recordedperiods
  a <- unname(sapply((split(hdata, rep(1:SamplesPerPeriod,recordedperiods))),mean ))
  return(a)
}
```

How can I improve the speed?

Would `rowMean` like in 
[Element-wise mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497464/element-wise-mean-in-r) 
be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a hint about `.rowMeans` here. I guess this is a good solution.